# Go storage client not able to access GCP bucket

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a golang service which has an API exposed where we try to upload a CSV to a GCP bucket. On my local host, I set the environment variable **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL**
and point this variable to the filepath of service account json. But when deploying to an actual GCP instance, I'm getting the below error while trying to access this API. Ideally,the service should talk to GCP metadata server and fetch the credentials and then store them in a json file. So there are 2 problems here:

1. Service is not querying the metadata service to get the credentials.
2. If file is present(I created it manually), it's not able to access due to permission issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

`Error while initializing storage Client:dialing: google: error getting credentials using well-known file (/root/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json): open /root/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json: permission denied`

Comment: The "permission denied" indicates that the user running your application has no read permission for the file. The /root directory by default is only accessible by the root user. Try to put your json to a directory where your application can read it and set the file permissions with chmod.

Comment: But in the first place, it should automatically query the metadata server, not sure why it isn't happening.

Comment: On Compute Engine, if you run `gcloud auth application-default login' or similar commands, that will supersede reading metadata for credentials. Execute the command `sudo gcloud auth application-default revoke`.

Comment: How have you set up your compute engine? Did you have set up environment variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after long debugging and searching over the web, found out that there's already an open PR for the go-storage client which is open: https://github.com/golang/oauth2/issues/337. I had to make a few changes in the code using this method: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2/google#ComputeTokenSource where in basically we are trying to fetch the token explicitly from metadata server and then calling subsequent cloud API's.